# Push multiple input strings to scope array, when input value changes (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, input

I am trying to add strings to an empty array i have defined in my scope.

```
$scope.playerNames = [];
```

The number of elements in the array can vary depending on what the user types in the player count input field.

Right now I have a `$watch` function which checks whether the user increments or decrements the player count and adds new input fields for names accordingly. For each of these input fields, i want to add a name to an array, when the user starts typing it. Value from the input field og the first player would be placed at index 0 and so on.

When the user decrements the player count, the player name (if any) should be removed from the array.

```
$scope.$watch('playerCount', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue > 7) {
            alert("Can't have more than 7 players.");
            $scope.playerCount = oldValue;
        }
        else if (newValue > oldValue) { //if increment player count
            $("#playerNames").append("<input id='player" + newValue +"' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter name for player" + newValue + "'>");

        }
        else if (newValue < oldValue) { //i decrement player count
            console.log("Removing")
            $("#player" + oldValue).remove();
        }
    });
```

Here's an example of how the form looks with 3 players: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XHqw.png

Am i thinking of this problem correctly? Is there a better way to do it? I'm not sure how I should go about binding my generated input forms to my array defined in the scope.

Comment: I tried using a for loop to both generate bind each input box to an index in the array: ng-model="playerNames[index]". But when i entered values into the input fields, the array remained empty.

Comment: Yeah, no. Yet someone else mixing up Angular and jQuery together. People, please STOP doing that. Use Angular OR jQuery. Do things the Angular way, OR the jQuery way. You're currently trying to make two very different things work together, and if you succeed at all, it will just be clumsy, messy and unmaintainable, not mentioning that you have to load two libraries instead of one.

Comment: Well, I'm using jQuery to select my HTML elements and I need it to make Bootstrap work anyway. I'm new to both frameworks, I don't know anything about mixing libraries or not. I don't doubt you're right, but that doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Here's a straightforward instruction then : Remove jQuery, or remove Angular :) And rework your app accordingly. This problem will then disappear. It comes directly from the fact that you are trying to make very different things work together.

Comment: You do not need to _select_ your HTML elements with jQuery then delete them, when they are _generated_ by Angular. Just tell Angular to _not_ generate them (remove element from array), and they'll be gone. That's how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. I've no idea why I didn't at first think about using angular directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use a `$scope.$watch`. You can do this by using `ng-repeat` over an array which has the same number of values as player count.

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.player={"count":0};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="player.count"/>
    <div>
            <div ng-repeat="player in  [].constructor(player.count) track by $index">
                <input id="player{{$index+1}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name for player {{$index+1}}" ng-model="player.value" />
            </div>
      </div>      
</body>
```

Comment: @Leth See? No jQuery.

Comment: You can avoid the constructor function and create a players array and loop through it. The players array should contain the same number of elements as the player count.

Comment: Thanks, this works as intended. I'm not sure how the constructor function works though. I will probably make a separate array for the players.

Comment: Yes, that will be better. For simplicty and laziness to write a function , I used constructor function which will return an array with the required number of values. But you could use ng-change on input and call a function to capture the player count, then create a players array(maybe an array of objects with name property that can be used to bind the ng-model).